# Read files in Meteor

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor

How can I read lines in files (csv, txt, etc.) with Meteor? I have seen multiple packages but many of them seem unmaintained and have a lot of dependencies. I think it might be quite simple to just read the data from them without saving them anywhere?

Answer (score 0):

I think the straight forward way to go would be to use standard node modules. This should point you in the right direction:

```
var fs = Npm.require('fs');
fs.readFile('filename.csv', function (err, data) {
  if (err) throw err;
  console.log(data);
});
```

Of course you may prefer fs.createReadStream() if you want to read a bigger file.

Just remember that this will only work on server side (it will throw an error on the client).

Comment: Hey thanks. But it will only work if the file is already on the server. How can I also read from a file from the computer?

Comment: If you need to read the contents of files from a client's computer, you first need to upload the file from the client's computer to the server before you can read it. This is useful if the server needs to store the contents anyway. If it doesn't, then the file can always be removed after processing. I would recommend using https://github.com/felixge/node-formidable to upload the client file. You can find an excellent tutorial on the usage at http://www.devbattles.com/sand/post-34-Upload+file+in+Node.js+using+formidable.

Comment: Thank you. I will take a look at formidable. Where can I manually locate the files on the server in Meteor if I choose not to upload them through the client?